# How to get the width of an Image and use the value as height to make the image fairly square

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I'm using the following code to get the width of an image who's width is in percentages. So i get the width in pixels which is what i want, but i can't seem to get the syntax of putting the variable inside the CCS property value with JavaScript.

This is my problem

```
$("#ProPhotosID").css("height", '' + height + '')
```

as seen in full here.

```
var img = document.getElementById("ProPhotosID"); 
var height = img.clientHeight;
$("#ProPhotosID").css("height", '' + height + '')
```

Thanks.

Comment: This `img.clientHeight` was giving you only the pixels as `int` of the same height that you already have. Using your approach would be: `$("#ProPhotosID").css("height", img.clientWidth + 'px')`

Comment: I like this a lot @Rudy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all you need:

```
$('#ProPhotosID').css('height', $('#ProPhotosID').css('width'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary quote `'` you only need to put the variable.
After you need to be secure that img.clientHeight is a real value.
Try this:

```
$("#ProPhotosID").css("height",  height);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap the variable with `'`. You can just put the variable.
Do something like this:

```
$("#ProPhotosID").css("height",height)
```

Or the simpler is just use `height()` instead of `css('heght', )`:

```
$('#ProPhotosID').height(height);
```